# AES256 encryption with golang

Tags: go, encryption, openssl, aes

I wrote a quick function in golang to encrypt my payload as an AES256 CBC string before writing to disk. The program (once compiled) appears to be doing just that (as confirmed using this [site](https://www.devglan.com/online-tools/aes-encryption-decryption) to decrypt), however using this OpenSSL command I get a final block length error. Can someone please help me? Thanks!

Keys:

```py
export AES_KEY=$(python -c 'import uuid;print(uuid.uuid4().hex)')
export AES_IV=$(python -c 'import uuid;print(uuid.uuid4().hex[:16])')
```

```
func AesEncrypt(plaintext string) (string, error) {
    key := GetEnv("AES_KEY", "")
    iv := GetEnv("AES_IV", "")
    if key == "" || iv == "" {
        return "", errors.New("AES_KEY and AES_IV must be set")
    }
    bKey := []byte(key)
    bIV := []byte(iv)
    bPlaintext := PKCS5Padding([]byte(plaintext), aes.BlockSize)
    block, err := aes.NewCipher(bKey)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    ciphertext := make([]byte, len(bPlaintext))
    mode := cipher.NewCBCEncrypter(block, bIV)
    mode.CryptBlocks(ciphertext, bPlaintext)
    return base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(ciphertext), nil
    // return hex.EncodeToString(ciphertext), nil
}

func PKCS5Padding(ciphertext []byte, blockSize int) []byte {
    padding := (blockSize - len(ciphertext)%blockSize)
    padtext := bytes.Repeat([]byte{byte(padding)}, padding)
    return append(ciphertext, padtext...)
}

func AesDecrypt(ciphertext string) (string, error) {
    key := GetEnv("AES_KEY", "")
    iv := GetEnv("AES_IV", "")
    if key == "" || iv == "" {
        return "", errors.New("AES_KEY and AES_IV must be set")
    }
    bKey := []byte(key)
    bIV := []byte(iv)
    // base64 decode
    cipherTextDecoded, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(ciphertext)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    // cipherTextDecoded, err := hex.DecodeString(cipherText)

    block, err := aes.NewCipher(bKey)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    mode := cipher.NewCBCDecrypter(block, bIV)
    mode.CryptBlocks([]byte(cipherTextDecoded), []byte(cipherTextDecoded))
    return string(cipherTextDecoded), nil
}
```

OpenSSL command to decrypt (after exporting file using go binary):

```bash
openssl aes-256-cbc -d -a -v -nosalt \
    -K $AES_KEY \
    -iv $AES_IV \
    -in variables.enc -out variables.dec
```

results in:

```
bad decrypt
8503165248:error:06FFF06D:digital envelope routines:CRYPTO_internal:wrong final block length:/AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/9e200cfa-7d96-11ed-886f-a23c4f261b56/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-3.3/crypto/evp/evp_enc.c:540:
```

Comment: Many encryptions require padding to a specific block boundary. Maybe this is a symptom of not doing that.

Answer (score 1):

For decryption to work with OpenSSL (s. [enc](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/enc.html)):

- key and IV must be specified hex encoded in the OpenSSL statement.
- the -A option must be set in addition to -a so that the data is to be read from a single line.

Both are missing. If this is added, decryption works with OpenSSL.

---

Test:

With the Python code, e.g. the following key and IV are generated:

```
Key: eaba2d73e2474eed9c3352f5aefe50e3
IV:  26e67818dfa848c2
```

Assuming that `GetEnv()` returns the strings generated by the Python code, key and IV result as UTF8 encoding of both strings (e.g. `bKey := []byte(key)`). The Go code then generates for the plaintext:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
```

the ciphertext:

```
157JLDOTKOuOV2UGaa+HcZUyZrjIRA/gbUGYcW5IQZQmNF4McKoDztk3gJcnqnSGBKGDG+beHvmmz5AS1vr1fjIKmpgOsIK8e4ZmTlg2z/nL5h1C8/9+vYTCZ8U3l/vNdlvrObdzEIzu5m/4mEWgZlvgZo+vsN8t9gZfj5Gw7uc=
```

This can be decrypted with OpenSSL as follows:

```
openssl aes-256-cbc -d -a -A -nosalt -K 6561626132643733653234373465656439633333353266356165666535306533 -iv 32366536373831386466613834386332 -in <path to encrypted data file> -out <path to decrypted data file>
```

where key and IV are specified hex encoded and the -A option is set (note that the -nosalt option has no effect when -K and -iv are set.)

---

Notes:

- In the Go code, the unpadding is missing. By the way, PKCS#7 is implemented by the [pkcs7pad](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/zenazn/pkcs7pad) package (although `PKCS5Padding()` seems to be OK).
- An AES key should be a random byte sequence. [`UUID.hex`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html#uuid.UUID.hex) returns a 32 bytes lowercase hex string. When this is used as key for AES-256, security is reduced because each byte is narrowed to 16 values (versus 256 values).

Comment: Thanks! Ya the way I was doing it didnt make that much sense, I switched to using GCM and generating the IV/nonce each time I encrypt and prepending it to the ciphertext. Honestly much simpler, not sure if its more or less secure though but should be fine for this purpose